# how to print object results in a textarea?

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm new at JAVA and Im using netbeans 
and I wanted to print the result of an object that has information that I want in a textarea
how can I do that?

this is part of my code

```
String referance= ref.getText();
String hypothesis=hyp.getText();

    WordSequenceAligner werEval = new WordSequenceAligner();
    String [] ref = referance.split(" ");
    String [] hyp = hypothesis.split(" ");

    WordSequenceAligner.Alignment a = werEval.align(ref, hyp);
    result.append(a);
```

I want to print object a.  `result` is the name of the textarea instance.

Comment: What type of Object is `textarea`? You could try something like this: `result.setText(a.toString());`

Answer (score 1):

```
JTextArea result = new JTextArea("Welcome stakoverflow.com",5,20);

result.setText("this is a text area");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `tostring` method for your `WordSequenceAligner.Alignment` class.

In order to print object's information you need to override `toString` method for that class, so that whenever you call `toString` on that class's object it will return string of your preference :

Here is a simple example :

```
class A{
int a = 10;

public String toString(){
 String myString = "This is an object of class A. It  has x = "+x;

 return myString;
}

}
```

So now when you call `toString` on an instance/object of class A, it will return that string that you have made instead of the hash value of that object.

```
public class Test{
 public static void main(String args[]){

  A a = new A();
  System.out.println(a);
  // or System.out.println(a.toString());
  // will output "This is an object of class A. It  has x = 10"

}
```

Comment: I'm not so sure about this answer since `toString()` in my experience is usually used as a way to simply show an object's state, such as for debugging purposes, but not usually too good a tool for production code to display information to an end user.